# Can I parse a String to Time in java

Tags: android

I am using android.text.format.Time and i need to have a function which gets a string and converts that string into a Time object. I initially stored the time object as string for some other reason. I just need to pasre teh string into Time object now. 
Code:

```
 Time time = new Time();
 String time = time.toString();

  Time t = new Time();
  t.parse(time);
  this.time = t;
```

Now

```
t.parse(time)
```

gives a boolean value.

```
boolean value = time.parse(s)
```

Parameters:
time -   the string to parse 
Returns:
true  - if the resulting time value is in UTC time

Comment: So what is the question? It looks like you answered the question by yourself. Unless the Time does not have parse method and you are asking how to implement your one parse method.

Answer (score 4):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse("2012-12-14 14:05:59");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
Time time = new Time();
time.set(int second, int minute, int hourOfDay, int monthDay, int month, int year);

// int second => calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
// etc minute, hourOfDay, monthOfDay, month, year...
```