# How to parse time in android

Tags: android, datetime, time

**Class Utils**

```
public static String getTimeAgo(String time) {

    String time_ago = "";
    try {
        // SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date past = format.parse(time);
        Date now = new Date();
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
        long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime());

        if (seconds < 60) {
            time_ago = seconds + " seconds ago";
        } else if (minutes < 60) {
            time_ago = seconds + " minutes ago";
        } else if (hours < 24) {
            time_ago = hours + " hours ago";
        } else {
            time_ago = days + " days ago";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return time_ago;
}
```

**Model**

```
public class History{
.....
String mTime;

public String getTime() {
return Utils.getTimeAgo(mTime);

}

public void setTime(String mTime) {
this.mTime = mTime;
}
}
```

This is **getView** in **Adapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder holder;
if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_history, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.mTvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    holder.mTvMediaName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_mediaName);
    holder.mTvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
    holder.mImageUrl = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_url);
    view.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
final History history = mListHistory.get(position);
holder.mTvTitle.setText(history.getTitle());
holder.mTvMediaName.setText(history.getMediaName());
holder.mTvTime.setText(history.getTime());
holder.mImageUrl.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
Picasso.with(mContext).load(history.getImageUrl())
        //.fit().centerInside()
        .into(holder.mImageUrl);

return view;
}
```

I set String time = "2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z";

holder.mTvTime.setText(history.getTime()); not display values

this is bug:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "43 days ago" (at offset 2)
```

Comment: remove the Z from your date format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875359/can-i-parse-a-string-to-time-in-java

Comment: What is the 000Z ? Help me!

Comment: I have a problem. I post question under. Please. Help me!

Comment: I update my question. Please. Help me!

Comment: These extra comments of the form "Please. Help me!" do **not** help you. No one will give post an answer any faster or any better.

Comment: @HaNguyen What is the format of date in `mTime`?

Answer (score 0):

T is used to separate the date from the time. Z means "Zulu time" (UTC).

To parse this try this date format,

```
try {
        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date past = format.parse("2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z");
        DebugTool.logD("TIMEEE " + now.getTime());
        DebugTool.logD("TIMEEE PAST" + past.getTime());
   } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z#8405125) SO thread for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

**with**

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault());
```

**OR**

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: @HaNguyen ok then, I will help you. Can you show what is your current `mTime` ?